# Add Angular 4 seed project theme to asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, bootstrap-themes

I need some certain views from a theme to be added to asp.net core project.
I was able to add the whole theme by

**1. Adding css, js, images, email_templates, etc to the wwwroot folder from Full Project Folder (of the theme).**

**2. Then in Controller/HomeController.cs added a view to the index constructor which in my case the view was Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file (in which the code is from index.html of the template)**

But then I was told to add only some theme files from the 'Seed' project of the template and only one certain dashboard and some other views specified which I don't know how to find them inside the theme.
I don't know how to proceed and where to start from. How can I get certain views from the theme and add them to asp.net core project ?

PS: I searched for tutorials or articles but they only show how to get the whole theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way to do this was to copy all the folders and files provided by the theme to the ClientApp folder, in my main app, then run it using 'ng serve'. From there I was able to edit them and use it as I wanted.